flutter errro build an with emulator
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:extractDebugAnnotations'.


Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':path_provider_android:detachedConfiguration1'.
Could not load module metadata from C:\Users\ACER.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.101\descriptors\com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains\uast\30.3.0\11cd36a7dcab7d14d0c14c5e6c7582e3\descriptor.bin


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
no idea i am try to restart the emulator cold restart

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your problem is unclear but you can follow the following brute force to resolve it.

Try flutter upgrade -> restart project -> flutter clean -> flutter pub get
Make sure that the Gradle version being used is compatible with your project. You can specify the Gradle version in the android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file.
Delete Flutter SDK and download it again and restart your project.
If nothing above works then reinstall Flutter. (Not Preferred)

